# What is a Command Object in C#?

Tags: c#, object, command

I have this assignment for my Software Engineering class (CS322) in which we need to use "simple command objects" on stacks in order to implement an undo/redo for our spreadsheet application (undo/redo cell background color changes and text changes).

Before today I had never heard of command objects. I have been looking around the internet and have narrowed down my understanding of command objects as essentially an

> "object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time" (wikipedia).

So it makes sense to me what exactly I am trying to do, but I really have very little clue to the implementation of such an object.

Does C# .NET have any default implementation of a command object that I can derive from?  And what is the difference between a command object and simply using a Node that stores the previous value?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by reading up on the Command design pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/10/command-pattern-in-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no real "Command Object" in C#.

In my book to be a *Command* an entity has to be part of a **language**.

So a *Command Object* would hold one 'sentence' in the language. This could be a graphics language, formal like Logo or informal like the stuff you design to write a graphics programm. Here a Command Object could be something like `Draw a Circle of Size r at Point m with Pen p` or `Set the current brush to color c`.

For your project it might be stuff like `'Color a cell c in the sheet with backcolor b'` or `Put text t into Cell c.` or `Calculate formula f for Cells <c> and pt the result into cell r`.

Undo/Redo Stacks can either store Commands or States. The former works only if commands can be either reversed (if you include some information about the previous state, like the last color) or if the last state can be inferred by redoing all commands from a known start (or from a snapshot.)

Or they store states which may or may not be expensive or complicated.

Before you code you should clarify the actual situation: What is the minimal set of cammands that make up the language. What are the maximum extensions you might have/want to handle.

And you should write a list of all the command words and their parameters. Don't code anything before you have written down the `Specs.`  In a nice talk in the recent Build conference on ["Thinking for Programmers"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-642) the recurring theme was *"To write good programms you have to think and in order to think you must write. The specs. If you don't you may think you think but you're not."*

Once you're there, you can create a command class which would hold the parameters like command type, values and also one or even more delegates/actions that must be called to do the actual work.

Or you might decide to stack states, but that wouldn't be really a command object stack then..